# HasCustomAttribute tag value 19 in FSharp.Core.dll

Tags: f#

In FSharp.Core.dll (4.0.30319.1) I found `HasCustomAttribute` tag with value 19. This value is not specified in ECMA-335. ECMA-335 (Part II, 24.2.6) describes only values from 0 to 18.

Anybody knows what mean with value?

**Update:**

Seems like tag (19) specify `GenericParamTable`.
[`Core.EqualityConditionalOnAttribute` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee353419.aspx)
[`Collections.Map<'Key,'Value>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee353686.aspx)
but 6th version of Reflector does not show attributes on generic parameters of `FSharp.Core.Collections.FSharpMap` type.

**Update 2:**

Question is closed. Answer in 5th edition of ECMA-335. (I used 4th edition).

Comment: What did you find this attribute on?

Comment: I can't say to which object this custom attribute is applyed. I can say only type of that custom attributes: Microsoft.FSharp.Core.EqualityConditionalOnAttribute Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ComparisonConditionalOnAttribute

Comment: These two attributes are applied to generic type parameters (which isn't often done in other .NET langauges), but I'm not exactly sure what are you refering to... (Section 23.2.6 of ECMA spec is about `LocalVarSig`, which doesn't seem to be related?)

Comment: @Tomas: He means 24.2.6 of the ECMA spec. I fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, I used old edition of ECMA-335. In 5th version HasCustomAttribute tag specified from 0 to 21.

Answer (score 2):

ECMA 335 5th edition specifies 19 as `GenericParam`. Partition II Section 22.20 has this to say about it:

> The *GenericParam* table stores the generic parameters used in generic type definitions and generic method definitions. These generic parameters can be constrained (i.e., generic arguments shall extend some class and/or implement certain interfaces) or unconstrained. (Such constraints are stored in the *GenericParamConstraint* table.)